# Wait for eventlisteners to finish after invoking event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, event-listener, jquery-events

I have seen many similar questions, but none have actually answered my issue. I would think it would be simple, but I guess it is not because JS is single-threaded.

Basically, I want to extract information from an html element which is being inserted through an `eventlistener` waiting for a click on a specific html element. With jQuery it looks like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendBack) {
        $(".clickme").click(); // Invoke 
        var result = $("#main-text").attr("src"); // Exists only when ".clickme" was clicked
        sendBack(result);
});
```

The problem with the preceding code is that `#main-text` does only exist **after** a specific event-listener of `.clickme`s `click`-event was executed.
And the `eventlisteners`are not executed before I assign `result` its value.
How do I wait for the event-listener to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's unknown how long it might take for the attribute to change, I'd use MutationObserver:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendBack) {
  $(".clickme").click();

  var target = $("#main-text")[0];
  new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    if (target.src) {
      sendBack(target.src);
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  }).observe(target, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['src'],
  });

  // keep the message channel open while waiting
  return true;
});
```

Otherwise a simple setTimeout might do the trick.
Just don't forget `return true` to keep the channel open.